# SQL Server TDE with PKI - converting P12/PKX to PVK/DER format

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption

To use TDE for SQL Server we are obliged to use a PKI certificate. The certificate has the format .p12(.pkx). Microsoft offeres a [certficate converter for SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2914662). Using it - it creates three certificates and one pvk file.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\PVKConverter>PVKConverter.exe -i D:\path\nameofpkicert.pkx -o mycert -d Password -e Password2
Processed PFX certificate D:\path to generat
e 3 PVK/DER certificate pairs.
Generated PVK/DER certificate pairs:
(mycert_1.cer)
(mycert_2.cer)
(mycert_3.cer, mycert_3.pvk)
```

How do I import this files to a SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work with mycert_3.cer:

```
USE master;
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password';
GO

USE master
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password';
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE TestCert  
FROM FILE = 'D:\path\mycert_3.cer'   
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'D:\path\mycert_3.pvk',   
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password2');  
GO 

USE TDE_Test
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE TestCert;
GO

ALTER DATABASE TDE_Test
SET ENCRYPTION ON;
GO
```